# Does POP3 distinguishes between read and unread messages

Tags: perl, pop3, email-client

I am working with Perl and using `Net::POP3`...

My code is able to get all the mails however I could not find any method in the documentation that can distinguish between read and unread messages.

IMAP does that, so I wanted to know if the same applies to POP3?

PS:: `ping()` method in `Net::POP3` is not listed as capability of `Net::POP3`

Comment: POP3 can only fetch mails. The server doesn't care about read or unread, flagged/starred/marked or about moved messages. It's just for receiving (and usually deleting afterwards).

Comment: You are not expected to leave messages on the server with POP (though it is common practice now), so a concept of a read/unread message makes no sense. IMAP, on the hand, is built around the concept of a remote mailbox. It can do many things POP can't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With POP3 it is not possible to distinguish between *read* or *unread*. It can only fetch and delete messages. All messages that have not been fetched by the client (which remembers that itself) are regarded as not new by the client if it fetches new messages. The server doesn't care about the state of a message. It just gives you all the messages it has.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol):

> POP supports simple download-and-delete requirements for access to
>   remote mailboxes (termed maildrop in the POP RFC's).[3] Although most
>   POP clients have an option to leave mail on server after download,
>   e-mail clients using POP generally connect, retrieve all messages,
>   store them on the user's PC as new messages, delete them from the
>   server, and then disconnect. Other protocols, notably IMAP, (Internet
>   Message Access Protocol) provide more complete and complex remote
>   access to typical mailbox operations.